# Getting two different types of value from two tables and show in gridview template

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a little confusing scenario here.I have got 2 tables.One table stores the new users who have registered(tblAllUsers) and another one stores the new events created(tblAllEvents).Now i want to display the combination of both tables in a gridview ORDER BY Registration datetime such that:

if the latest value comes in from tblAllUsers,it should show
   "Michael just registered on the website" where Michael is the firstname of the user in tblallusers

and if value comes in from tblAllEvents,it should show 
   "Piano Exhibition was created by User34" where Piano Exhibition is the EventName in tblAllEvents

By far I've tried to create a union of two tables like :

```
 Select FirstName,RegDateTime from tblAllUsers 
 UNION ALL
 Select EventName,RegDateTime from tblAllEvents
 ORDER BY RegDateTime DESC
```

but the above gives out FirstName and Title under column FirstName and will be hard to distinguish.

How do i design my gridview template for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your query like this:

```
SELECT     FirstName, NULL AS EventName, RegDateTime 
FROM       tblAllUsers 
UNION ALL
SELECT     NULL, EventName, RegDateTime 
FROM       tblAllEvents
ORDER BY   RegDateTime DESC
```

So now you have three columns and FirstName or EventName is filled depending on which table it comes from.

In your GridView you can test which value is empty (EventName or FirstName) and change the text accordingly.

**EDIT:**
You could even return only the first row (with the latest RegDateTime):

```
SELECT      TOP 1 *
FROM        (SELECT     FirstName, NULL AS EventName, RegDateTime 
            FROM        tblAllUsers
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      NULL, EventName, RegDateTime 
            FROM        tblAllEvents) AS a
ORDER BY    RegDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Thank you.that would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally add an `event type` column and use it to check how to handle it on the grid view

```
 Select 'User' as EventType, FirstName,RegDateTime from tblAllUsers 
 UNION ALL
 Select 'Event' as EventType, EventName,RegDateTime from tblAllEvents
 ORDER BY RegDateTime DESC
```

You might need to add the user name as well in the `'Event'` since you also show the name of the user who created the event

Comment: Yes, i was going to do that too.Thank you